# Dialog with which contain fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to make a `Dialog` which contains a `Fragment`,
I used `DialogFragment` and it works fine for the first time when the dialog's open,
but when I try to open the dialog again, it crashes.

here is the code:

```
public class Map_dialog extends DialogFragment {
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());      
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.map, null);
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                 mMap  = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                            R.id.map)).getMap();
                  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // set the current location

                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                alertDialogBuilder

                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                            }

});
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();         
} }
```

here is the XML code:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >`



  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></LinearLayout>
```

It doesn't matter if I use a map or not, I tried to make a simple fragment that doesn't include map
and it still crashes at the second time.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: "it crashes" -> LogCat

Comment: 09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
09-16 16:29:38.200: E/AndroidRuntime(23321):